# how to consider modification time (mtime) by mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

Is it possible to consider modification time (mtime) of file by mod_rewrite?

What I want to do is:

- when accessed to '*.html':

  - return '*.html' when it exists and is newer than '*.html.eruby'.
  - rewrite into '*.html.eruby' when '*.html' doesn't exist or is older than '*.html.eruby'.

my .htaccess:

```
## inhibit direct access to *.eruby
RewriteRule \.eruby$ - [R=404,L]

## rewrite *.html into *.html.eruby when *.html.eruby exists
## (TODO: rewrite only when *.html.eruby is newer than *.html)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.eruby -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.eruby
```

Comment: The last time I looked into the same problem I found it to be not possible. +1 though for asking, if there is a solution I'd like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there's a solution. I sell it $100 000 000 (close friend's price). Just kidding.

To solve this, use RewriteMap directive that executes an external "filter". See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).
From the website, with emphasis on what you may look:

> External Rewriting Program
>
> MapType: prg, MapSource: Unix filesystem path to valid regular file Here the source is a program, not a map file. To create it *you can
>   use a language of your choice*, but the result has to be an executable
>   program (either object-code or a script with the magic cookie trick
>   '#!/path/to/interpreter' as the first line).
>
> This program is started once, when the Apache server is started, and
>   then communicates with the rewriting engine via its stdin and stdout
>   file-handles.

So my advice: make a very simple program in python that compares timestamps of the two files.

See [here for a sample in Perl](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/apache/2005/04/28/apacheckbk.html).

Comment: Ah right, I came across this as well but had to dismiss it as unworkable on my host at the time... +1 for the reminder, will use it when I have the right server for it. :o)

Comment: RewriteMap directive seems not available with '.htaccess'. It works only with 'httpd.conf'.

Comment: RewriteMap directive is not available with `.htaccess`, you're right.